# Angular2 How can i Use One Component function In Another Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

Here i Have 2 Component Like CacadingComponent And LoginComponent I want To Consume CacadingComponent  function in LoginComponent

**CacadingComponent**

```
export class CascadingComponent {
   CountryList: Country[];
   constructor(private _CacadeService: CascadindService) {       
   }
    GetCountry() {
        return this._CacadeService.GetCountryList().subscribe((data) => this.CountryList = data);
    }
```

**LoginComponent.ts**

Here i want to call GetCountry() Function In my LoginComponent

```
export class LoginComponent{
//Here How can I call
}
```

Comment: You can use a service if you want to have shared functionalities, etc. 
Also, you might use the component inside your component's view.

Comment: Yes @Dawid But Requirement is Something  Different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{
    @ViewChild(CascadingComponent) cascadingComponent: CascadingComponent ;
    ngOnInit(){
    this.cascading.GetCountry();}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access method by making object of class `CascadingComponent` as shown below :

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{

       cascadingComponent = new CascadingComponent();

       ngOnInit(){
         this.cascadingComponent.GetCountry();
      }
}
```